# Getting a error message when creating a table

Tags: formatting

I am trying to create a descriptive statistics table and when I do so I get this error message 'Extra} or forgotten endgroup' though the code is able to compile and produce an output

```
\begin{table}[htbp]}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}\hline\hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} &  \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N}\\ \hline
\emph{Sociodemographic Characteristics} & & & & &  \\

\end{tabular}
\label{tab:desc1}
\end{table}
```

Comment: \begin{table}[htbp]}
\caption{Descriptive Statistics}

\centering
\begin{tabular}{l c c c c c}\hline\hline

\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Variable}} & \textbf{Mean}
 & \textbf{Std. Dev.}& \textbf{Min.} &  \textbf{Max.} & \textbf{N}\\ \hline
....
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\label{tab:desc1}
\end{table}

Answer (score 2):

`\begin{table}[htbp]}`.  Extra closing brace.  Use `\begin{table}[htbp]`